# Can this Play template code be simplified (avoid if/else tag)?

Tags: templates, groovy, playframework

I have the following html code:

```
#{if title == 'Subnet' }
    <li><a href="@{SubnetController.list}" class="selected">&{'subnet'}</a></li>
#{/if}
#{else}
    <li><a href="@{SubnetController.list}">&{'subnet'}</a></li>
#{/else}
```

Is it possible to do that with less code, maybe using a groovy operator I am not aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<li><a href="@{SubnetController.list}" #{if title == 'Subnet'} class="selected" #{/if} >&{'subnet'}</a></li>
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

following should also do the trick:

```
<li><a href="@{SubnetController.list}" #{title == 'Subnet'? 'class="selected"' : ''}>&{'subnet'}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use custom tags to encapsulate presentation logic in my templates so in your case, I'd have:

```
<li><appName:subnetLink title=${title} /></li>
```

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

following should also do the trick:

```
 <li> <a href="@{SubnetController.list}" ${title == 'Subnet'? 'class="selected"'.raw() : ''}> 
 ${'subnet'}</a></li>
```